# Chrome don't share tab and firefox can't download screen in screen sharing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, screensharing

I'm following this example https://codepen.io/remusnegrota/pen/bGNpERz

On Firefox if you select the entire screen, you can't download afterwards (it works if you select the current tab)
On chrome it works if you select the entire screen, but shows up all the tabs except the current one.

I'm on Windows 11 with Firefox on version 112.0.2 (64-bits) and chrome 112.0.5615.138 64 bits

I tried a few options on `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia` like

```
const gdmOptions = {
  video: {
    displaySurface: "window",
  },
  audio: {
    echoCancellation: true,
    noiseSuppression: true,
    sampleRate: 44100,
    suppressLocalAudioPlayback: true,
  },
  surfaceSwitching: "include",
  selfBrowserSurface: "exclude",
  systemAudio: "exclude",
};
```

but no success...